# Merging two tables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have created two tables and am trying to merge them but for some reason it's not working.

My two tables are:

```
table_account_id = data1.groupby('employer_key').account_id.nunique() #how many people logged in (unique account id)

table_eligible = data3.groupby(['employer_key'])[['eligible']].sum().astype('int') #eligible population
```

I want my new table to have the following columns:

```
Employer_key // account_id // eligible
```

I thought the code would be the following but it isn't working:

```
new_table = pd.merge(table_eligible, table_account_id, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I was able to merge these two tables until I inserted the nunique function into my table_account_id code.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your DataFrames into your question (or some representative sample data), and detail what "isn't working"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone and you didn't post data. Crossing my fingers that this works.

```
table_eligible.join(table_account_id).reset_index()
```